# How to insert multiple data in one textbox usingJjavaScript and MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have inserted multiple values into one textbox but the data was not inserted into the table. How to solve this problem?

```
<input id="txtlocName" placeholder="Location Name" type="text class="form-control">

$('#txtlocName').selectize({
       delimiter: ',',`
       persist: false,
       create: function (input) {
            return {
                   value: input,
                    text: input
            }
       }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

check for adding dependencies of this jQuery plugin correctly:

look at one of the examples in the repository examples [link](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/tree/master/examples).
it is depended on `jquery.js`, `selectize.js`,`index.js` files and `stylesheet.css` files